# ELB + ECS + EFS + RDS amazon,cron job with magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, aws, loadbalancing

We are migrating our Magento 1.9 to AWS.
We have already implemented an RDS MySQL database, an EFS for static and PHP files. 
Alsa with we has a load balancer connected with for the moment 2 servers EC2.
My question is about the cron job on Magento.

Is there any way to use launch cron on my infra? My both EC2 are the same and I don't want to select a master just for my jobs. If there is a failover, I want my job is still running.
If I decide to put my cron in my both server, is it any risk that a task runs twice at the same time?

Also, if you are using elasticache, should I have an S3 or does it work with an EFS also?

Thanks a lot
Thomas